# Joining most recent record based on the date in another record

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables - let's call them `week` and `contract`, like so:

```
Week                                    Contract    
emp_id | starting   | data1 |  ...   emp_id | from_date  | data2 | ...
-------|------------|-------|--      -------|------------|-------|--
12     | 2019-01-08 | abcd  |        12     | 2018-08-01 | efgh  | 
12     | 2019-01-15 | abcd  |        13     | 2018-10-02 | efgh  | 
12     | 2019-01-22 | abcd  |        13     | 2019-01-15 | ijkl  | 
13     | 2019-01-08 | abcd  |        13     | 2019-03-19 | mnop  | 
13     | 2019-01-15 | abcd  |        14     | 2017-02-02 | efgh  | 
13     | 2019-01-22 | abcd  |        15     | 2018-01-19 | efgh  |
```

The `week.starting` field is a date (datetime with time set to midnight) that's at fairly regular intervals. The specific combination of (emp_id, starting) is unique. The `from_date` field is also a date that records the starting period where the `contract` record applies. This can be in the future, so we can't just do a `MAX(from)` and get the right contract for each employee. Currently, (emp_id, from_date) is unique, but I don't want to rely on this. `week.starting` and `contract.from_date` can be identical.

I want a query that returns the entire `week` record, and for each, the record for whatever `contract` was active at the time - that is, the record where `from_date` is largest while still less than or equal to `week.starting`. Getting this contract if I have a specific week in mind is a pretty straightforward greatest n-per-group problem:

```
SELECT * FROM contract 
WHERE contract.emp_id = @emp_id AND contract.from_date <= @starting
ORDER BY contract.from_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But I can't work out how to do this as part of a query to get every record in `week`. My specific combination of obstacles means I haven't been able to find an answer, despite this being a common set of problems. I don't appear to be able to pass `week.starting` into a subquery, and I don't appear to be able to use LIMIT in a join either. My best attempt so far ended up joining all contracts that were less than a given week.

What query will return the result I'm looking for?

```
emp_id | starting   | from_date  | data1 | data2 | ...
-------|------------|------------|-------|-------|--
12     | 2019-01-08 | 2018-08-01 | abcd  | efgh  |
12     | 2019-01-15 | 2018-08-01 | abcd  | efgh  |
12     | 2019-01-22 | 2018-08-01 | abcd  | efgh  |
13     | 2019-01-08 | 2018-10-02 | abcd  | efgh  |
13     | 2019-01-15 | 2019-01-15 | abcd  | ijkl  |
13     | 2019-01-22 | 2019-01-15 | abcd  | ijkl  |
```

Comment: On what bases you are giving condition for eg: for emp_id = 13 
13   -->   2019-01-08  --->  2018-10-02
13   -->    2019-01-15  -->   2019-01-15 
13   -->   2019-01-22  -->    2019-01-15

Comment: sorry, I made a typo in the example table. Some dates should have been 2019, not 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a window function to order the contracts in time after filtering future contracts and assign a rank. Then you can pick the latest with the top rank.

Have not tested this but should look something like:

```
select * from (
    select w.*, c.from_date, c.data2,
        row_number() over (partition by c.emp_id, w.starting order by c.from_date desc) as latest
    from week w
    join contract c on c.emp_id = w.emp_id and c.from_date <= w.starting
) as sub where latest = 1
```

Comment: You can use first_value(data2) instead of row_number() to eliminate the need for the outer select clause, see [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

Comment: First_value applies that result to each row in the window frame. Then you'd still have to check where first_value=from_date. It does not do the filtering for you. That might introduce dupes as well since could match more than once.

Comment: You're right. If you use `partition by c.emp_id, w.starting` you get the exact output OP was expecting (contract by employee for each week).

Comment: Wanted to point out, in some cases returning all the matching rows using first_value might be desirable.

Comment: I've just tried this on our dev database and it's working beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use a lateral join:

```
select w.*, c.*
from weeks w left join lateral
     (select c.*
      from contract c
      where c.emp_id = w.emp_id and
            c.from_date <= w.starting
      order by c.from_date desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) c;
```